# Android Remove imageView from a row inside a tableLayout

Tags: android, onclick, row, tablelayout

Please take a look at the code snippet below:

```
imageContainer.addView(imageA);
imageContainer.addView(imageB);
textContainer.addView(text);

row.addView(textContainer);
row.addView(imageContainer);
row.setId(i);

row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        //Try to remove this row's imageB when onClick
    }        
})
```

From the above code, how should the objective can be achieved if I would like to remove only imageB from that particular row when onClick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void onClick(View v){

    TableRow row= (TableRow) findViewById(v.getId());

    imageContainer=(<imageContainertype>) row.getChildAt(1);

    ImageView imageB =(ImageView) imageContainer.getChildAt(1);

    imageContainer.removeView(imageB);
}
```